# Extension PHP5 does not parse in XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I've installed XAMPP Apache server and put my website into htdocs. I've started Apache server. On my website I've got files with extension PHP and with extension PHP5.The difference is that when I type in into browser localhost/file.php - I see a parsed website.

But when I type localhost/file.php5 (i have this file on server), than browser asks me if I want to download or open this file. And if I choose open than I see PHP code of file.php5!

I've looked into configuration, so:

1. I dont have htaccess file
2. PHPINFO() shows PHP 5
3. c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp is included into configuration and has this on the beginning:

   AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

   AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php5 .php4 .php3 .phtml .phpt

I've tried also to put:

```
AddHandler php5-script .php5
AddType text/html .php5
```

Into httpd.conf, but it does not work for me (no changes).

Could you please help me fixing it? I would like to have php5 and php extension files to be opened with php5 parser.

Comment: have you restarted apache when you added .php5 to the configuration?

Comment: Yes, I've restared it after any change. Also I've tried with CGI version and with service version.

Comment: If you installed the xampp package, how can this possibly not work?!

Comment: did you make sure to restart apache after adding the handler types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XAMPP passes by default files with the following extensions to PHP: .php **.php5** .php4 .php3 .phtml .phpt (this was tested with XAMPP Lite 1.6.8).

My suggestion would be to remove the "AddType text/html .php5" line from the XAMPP configuration. Alternatively, use a clean install of XAMPP and look at the differences (with something like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)).

Answer (score 9):

1. Follow the path `c:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xammp`

   Open `httpd-xammp`
2. Find the area of the text that resembles this:

   ```
   <FilesMatch "\.php$"> 
      SetHandler application/x-httpd-php   
   </FilesMatch>
   <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
       SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
   </FilesMatch>
   ```
3. replace the top line of the code with the following:

   ```
   <FilesMatch "\.php$|\.php5$|\.php4$|\.php3$|\.phtml$|\.phpt$">
   ```
4. so the text resembles the following:

   ```
   <FilesMatch "\.php$|\.php5$|\.php4$|\.php3$|\.phtml$|\.phpt$"> 
       SetHandler application/x-httpd-php  
   </FilesMatch>
   <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
       SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
   </FilesMatch>
   ```

That worked for me.

Good luck..

Answer (score 0):

I had to figure out how to do this again when I switched to an Ubuntu OS. The file that needs to be modified is called `php5.conf`.

I installed apache 2, php5, phpmyadmin, mysql-server and rapache with the synaptic package manager (system> administration> synaptic package manager) and did not use XAMPP. If you have already installed XAMPP then the paths to `php5.conf` will be different, likely somewhere in the `/opt/lampp` file.

With my install, the path to it is `/etc/apache2/mods-avaible/php5.conf`. Before it can be modified you must use the terminal to change the permissions to allow you to write to it. To get to it, open the terminal and type :

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-available
```

and then line that changes the permissions:

```
sudo chmod a+w php5.conf
```

You can type the following to make sure the permissions have been changed:

```
ls -l
```

You should see a long list of files with the permission notions. The line for `php5.conf` should look like this (with the exception of the date and time):

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  139 2009-12-06 22:35 php5.conf
```

This means everyone has read and write permissions. You can change the permissions back when you get done if you want. For now proceed to make the changes you need by typing:

```
nano php5.conf
```

This opens the file in a kind of text editor. What you should see is this:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .php3
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</IfModule>
```

Change the text to read as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .php3 .php5
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</IfModule>
```

Adding the `.php5` to after the first `AddType` command.

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit and y to save changes. Then restart the computer. And then your files with the `.php5` extensions should work!

I can't believe that took me hours to figure out! Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Adding:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php5
```

worked for me under OS X and Apache 2.2.10, I cannot imagine it being different on XAMPP. I would undo all of your other changes/modifications to httpd.conf and then only have:

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php5
```

Then restart apache. Get rid of the AddHandler, the AddType, etc.

Comment: thanks.. 1st line worked for me.. I added .php5 in above line ..in httpd.conf