# How to run/execute .php5 in xampp?

Tags: php, xampp

I need to run a PHP project on XAMPP.

All PHP files ends with `.php5` extension.

When I just run those files it prints the PHP code instead of executing.

So, how can I execute .php5 in xampp?

Comment: @Quentin I think redirecting him to a .htaccess solution is not good. Those things should be solved by apache configuration and not htaccess. The linked question explicitly asks for .htaccess which is not the case here. https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/Htaccess *The use of .htaccess files is discouraged as they can have a detrimental effect on server performance. Only use them when necessary.*

Comment: @Xatenev Yes. It isn't the solution what I wanted. But another user suggest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460589/extension-php5-does-not-parse-in-xampp as a duplicate of this question.  I solved my question from that link. Thanks