# PHTML file unable to execute PHP code on XAMPP server localhost

Tags: php, xampp

I'm working on a project which contains .phtml files. When I open these files in a web browser, it only displays the text part, but it's unable to execute PHP code. I'm working on an XAMPP server localhost.

Comment: Please post your works in your question so that the problem can be identified easily.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460589/extension-php5-does-not-parse-in-xampp

Comment: i am viewing a file which is a .phtml file.But when i open it on my local server it treats php code as plain text

Comment: is there any way to enable phtml extension in apache in order to view .phtml file.I am using php 7.2 currently

Comment: Look at the link 04FS provided. The answer is there. You have a directive with `.php` somewhere and you just add `.phtml`, restart the server and it works. Also put some regards to what Sanip said. Put more details in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not the browser decides whether a page is interpreted as plain text or not, but the web server based on the MIME types defined. So you have to teach Apache what to do with phtml files because clairvoyance can not be clairvoyant and therefore decides to use your default / plain text if the file extension is unknown to it.

The following works with the Windows variant, but should look similar on Linux.

in the php.ini file in the php folder

```
change short_open_tags = off to on
```

You have to change 2 lines in the `httpd-xampp.conf` file in the bin folder

searching:
CODE: SELECT ALL

```
<FilesMatch "\ .php $">
```

replace by:
CODE: SELECT ALL

```
<FilesMatch "\. (Php | phtml) $">
```

and search
CODE: SELECT ALL

```
AddType text / html .php .phps
```

replace
CODE: SELECT ALL

```
AddType text / html .php .phps .phtml
```

Restart Apache